Running SDL on docker
When I run it in a container, my application freezes when creating the renderer with SDL_Renderer *renderer = (...).  This happens with native SDL, but I've seen similar problems with frameworks like pygame (on python).
Also, I could run, on the same container, xeyes and a simple tkinter app. So the communication with the host display works fine.
I wrote this simple sdl with c program (and yes, it works on my machine):
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;

int main() {

    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("SDL initialized\n");

    // Create a window
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pixel Drawing", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, 0);
    if (!window) {
        SDL_Log("Unable to create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Window created\n");

    // Create a renderer
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!renderer) {
        SDL_Log("Unable to create renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Renderer created\n");

    // Draw a rectangle (larger shape) instead of a single pixel
    SDL_Rect rect = {100, 100, 10, 10}; // x, y, width, height
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255); // Set color to red
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect); // Fill the rectangle with the specified color

    printf("Rectangle drawn\n");

    // Present renderer
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    // Wait for the user to close the window
    SDL_Event event;
    while (1) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            break;
        }
    } 

    // Cleanup
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

I don't think its useful but here you have the Dockerfile anyways:
# Dockerfile for sdl2 development

FROM debian

# Install normal dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        wget \
        zsh \
        vim \
        dbus-x11 \
        gdb \
        x11-apps \
        x11-utils \
        x11-xserver-utils \
        procps \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"

# Install SDL2 dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        libsdl2-dev

# Generating a universally unique ID for the Container
RUN dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id

# Update the package list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

WORKDIR /workspace

# Execute /workspace/app/test
CMD ["./app/test"]

To get it to work, I used strace to check systemcalls and find out what's happening.
I found interesting that this was repeated indefinitely:
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1)    = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(4, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="#\203\234\0\n\0\0\0\21\0\2\0\335\263(\0\0\0\0\0\17\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 72

I searched for this file descriptor 4 with ls -l /proc/PID/fd/4 and got socket:[294329].
Ok, so it is trying to communicate with a socket, possibly the xserver socket?
The command ss -aen | grep 294329 made me sure:
u_str ESTAB     0      213248                                                           /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 294330             * 294329 <-> ino:3145895 dev:0/49                         
u_str ESTAB     19848  0                                                                                * 294329             * 294330 <->

So, resuming it it trying to communicate with the x11 server but it's not getting any response back.
So, now what? What makes sdl not work in docker but other programs do?
